# elasticsearch filter charachter in keyword and text data types

Tags: elasticsearch

I need change some characters in my index in keyword and text data types.
for do that, i want to add same character map filter to keyword analyzer and language specific analyzer in my project.
the solution that i have chosen is:
create two custom analyzer that extends language specific analyzer and keyword analyzers and then use them in my field.
and there is my implementation:

```
"analysis": {
  "analyzer": {
    "persian_text_analyzer": {
      "type": "persian",
      "char_filter": [
        "arabic_to_persian_filter"
      ]
    },
    "persian_keyword_analyzer": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "char_filter": [
        "arabic_to_persian_filter"
      ]
    }
  },
  "char_filter": {
    "arabic_to_persian_filter": {
      "type": "mapping",
      "mappings": [
        "\u0660 => 0",
        "\u0661 => 1",
        "\u0662 => 2",
        "\u0663 => 3",
        "\u0664 => 4",
        "\u0665 => 5",
        "\u0666 => 6",
        "\u0667 => 7",
        "\u0668 => 8",
        "\u0669 => 9",
        "\u064a => \u06cc",
        "\u0643 => \u06a9"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

but it does not work.
is it possible to extend existing analyzer and add some filters without override existing filters?

if not what can i do to solve my problem?

Comment: What does `$endpoint/$index/_analyze?analyzer=persian_keyword_analyzer&text=٠` say?

Comment: @jasonz
here is the result:
{
 "tokens": [
  {
   "token" : "٠",
   "start_offset" : 0,
   "end_offset" : 1,
   "type" : word,
   "position" : 0
  }
 ]
}

Comment: have you updated the setting of the index? because the result is supposed to be '{ "tokens": [ { "token": "0", "start_offset": 0, "end_offset": 1, "type": "word", "position": 0 }] }', at least on ES v2.3.5.

Comment: {"saeed_index1":{"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":"1","provided_name":"saeed_index1","creation_date":"1480777127855","analysis":{"analyzer":{"persian_text_analyzer":{"type":"persian","char_filter":["arabic_to_persian_filter"]},"persian_keyword_analyzer":{"type":"keyword","char_filter":["arabic_to_persian_filter"]}},"char_filter":{"arabic_to_persian_filter":{"type":"mapping","mappings":["٠ => 0","١ => 1","٢ => 2","٣ => 3","٤ => 4","٥ => 5","٦ => 6","٧ => 7","٨ => 8","٩ => 9","ي => ی","ك => ک"]}}},"number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"C7fzVqCAS5Oqj_l7Rgo2CA","version":{"created":"5000099"}}}}}

Comment: @jasonz previous comment is my full configuration

Comment: it works for me on ES v2.3.5 with the same setting...what's the version of ES? or update to the latest version?

Comment: i`m using version 5.0.0

Comment: @jasonz I have changed my configuration
my analyzer type is now custom and it works
so i need to apply persian analyzer and my custom analyzer on input terms.
how can i do that?
can i write custom analyzer that extends persian analyzer?
can i use multiple analyzer for my field?

Comment: 1. index with `multi_field` in mapping and query with `multi_match` to query with multiply analyzer 
2. modify this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#persian-analyzer to write custom analyzer
3. maybe same with 1?

Comment: thanks a lot. so i will modify persian analyzer to have a custom analyzer based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with tanks of @jasonz i have solved my problem
i have had 2 mistakes:
1- in

```
"persian_keyword_analyzer": {
      "type": "keyword",
```

type must be custom 
2- keyword type cannot have analyzer 
so here is my final configuration:

```
"settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "char_filter": {
        "zero_width_spaces": {
            "type":       "mapping",
            "mappings": [ "\u200c => \u0020"] 
        },
        "arabic_to_persian_filter": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            "\u0660 => 0",
            "\u0661 => 1",
            "\u0662 => 2",
            "\u0663 => 3",
            "\u0664 => 4",
            "\u0665 => 5",
            "\u0666 => 6",
            "\u0667 => 7",
            "\u0668 => 8",
            "\u0669 => 9",
            "\u064a => \u06cc",
            "\u0643 => \u06a9"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "persian_stop": {
          "type":       "stop",
          "stopwords":  "_persian_" 
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "persian_text_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer":     "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "zero_width_spaces",
            "arabic_to_persian_filter"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization",
            "persian_stop"
          ]
        },
        "persian_keyword_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer":     "keyword",
          "char_filter": [
            "zero_width_spaces",
            "arabic_to_persian_filter"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "arabic_normalization",
            "persian_normalization"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```